# Display Controls on Scroll

Tags: jquery

Is there an easy way to show a pane at the bottom of the page, when the user scrolls down beyond half the page and hides it when they scroll up. They should also be able to close it if they do not want to see it again, ever.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('#note').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#note').fadeOut();
        }
});

$("#note").click(function() {
        $("#note").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zvx8h/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `position:fixed` to keep your panel at the bottom with this:

```
#note{
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Then after the click remove the `scroll` event of the window like this:

```
$("#note").click(function() {
    $("#note").fadeOut("slow");
    $(window).off('scroll');
});
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Zvx8h/2/

Comment: this looks great. How do I implement a close button so that if user closes the pane, it is never showed to him/her. Probably something to do with a cookie but not sure.

Comment: You mean never never again? This hide the element until you reload again the pagae but to hide always you may need a cookie. @user3279259

Comment: yep any idea of how to implement a cookie in jQuery here so that it remembers and saves user preference. I checked some plugins online but I am not sure.

Comment: @user3279259 Nop I don't know about that theme... make a concret question about that topic or search a little

Comment: Np @user3279259 mate glad to help you. Also maybe with LocalStorage I hear some about that but don't know if can help you